# Spark streaming mapWithState timeout delayed?

Tags: java, apache-spark, timeout, spark-streaming

I expected the new mapWithState API for Spark 1.6+ to near-immediately remove objects that are timed-out, but there is a delay.

I'm testing the API with the adapted version of the [JavaStatefulNetworkWordCount](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaStatefulNetworkWordCount.java) below:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("JavaStatefulNetworkWordCount")
    .setMaster("local[*]");

JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(1));
ssc.checkpoint("./tmp");

StateSpec<String, Integer, Integer, Tuple2<String, Integer>> mappingFunc =  
    StateSpec.function((word, one, state) -> {
        if (state.isTimingOut())
        {
             System.out.println("Timing out the word: " + word);
             return new Tuple2<String,Integer>(word, state.get());
        }
        else
        {
            int sum = one.or(0) + (state.exists() ? state.get() : 0);
            Tuple2<String, Integer> output = new Tuple2<String, Integer>(word, sum);
            state.update(sum);
            return output;
        }
});

JavaMapWithStateDStream<String, Integer, Integer, Tuple2<String, Integer>> stateDstream =
    ssc.socketTextStream(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]),
     StorageLevels.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2)
       .flatMap(x -> Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(x)))
       .mapToPair(w -> new Tuple2<String, Integer>(w, 1))
       .mapWithState(mappingFunc.timeout(Durations.seconds(5)));

stateDstream.stateSnapshots().print();
```

Together with nc (`nc -l -p <port>`)

When I type a word into the nc window I see the  tuple being printed in the console every second. But it doesn't seem like the timing out message gets printed out 5s later, as expected based on the timeout set. The time it takes for the tuple to expire seems to vary between 5 & 20s.

Am I missing some configuration option, or is the timeout perhaps only performed at the same time as checkpoints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once an event times out it's *NOT* deleted right away, but is only marked for deletion by saving it to a 'deltaMap':

```
override def remove(key: K): Unit = {
  val stateInfo = deltaMap(key)
  if (stateInfo != null) {
    stateInfo.markDeleted()
  } else {
    val newInfo = new StateInfo[S](deleted = true)
    deltaMap.update(key, newInfo)
  }
}
```

Then, timed out events are collected and sent to the output stream *only at checkpoint*. That is: events which time out at batch t, will appear in the output stream only at the next checkpoint - by default, after 5 batch-intervals on average, i.e. batch t+5:

```
 override def checkpoint(): Unit = {
    super.checkpoint()
    doFullScan = true
  }

...

removeTimedoutData = doFullScan // remove timedout data only when full scan is enabled

...

// Get the timed out state records, call the mapping function on each and collect the
    // data returned
    if (removeTimedoutData && timeoutThresholdTime.isDefined) {
...
```

Elements are actually removed only when there are enough of them, and when state map is being serialized - which currently also happens only at checkpoint:

```
  /** Whether the delta chain length is long enough that it should be compacted */
  def shouldCompact: Boolean = {
    deltaChainLength >= deltaChainThreshold
  }
  // Write the data in the parent state map while copying the data into a new parent map for
    // compaction (if needed)
    val doCompaction = shouldCompact
...
```

By default checkpointing occurs every 10 iterations, thus in the example above every 10 seconds; since your timeout is 5 seconds, events are expected within 5-15 seconds.

EDIT: Corrected and elaborated answer following comments by @YuvalItzchakov

Comment: I'm looking at the code for `writeObjectInternal` and failing to understand where exactly the object gets removed from the `OpenHashMap` implementation. Also, this doesn't contradict my answer, it simply explains that deletion is deferred until checkpointing, and corrects my answer in the fact that it's only marked for deletion on each iteration of `mapWithState`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I agree your answer is technically correct, however I believe it does not correctly answer the question - the main cause for the delay experienced by the OP is probably the deferred deletion, not scheduling/ execution times (although I agree they take time too)

Comment: You're right. I'll update my answer to refer to the marking instead of the actual deletion.

Comment: @etov If it's not deleted why the isTimingOut still be false after the time out ?
Indeed after 10 iteration I see the isTimingOut to true.

Comment: @crak I'm not sure I understand the question, please elaborate / make more precise. Generally though events are timed out only at checkpoint, regardless of when they're deleted

Comment: @etov I had miss that it's not a TTL but a idle timeout. So of course while the stream still see event, the state do no timing out.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing some configuration option, or is the timeout perhaps only
>   performed at the same time as snapshots?

Every time a `mapWithState` is invoked (with your configuration, around every 1 second), the `MapWithStateRDD` will internally check for expired records and time them out. You can see it in the code:

```
// Get the timed out state records, call the mapping function on each and collect the
// data returned
if (removeTimedoutData && timeoutThresholdTime.isDefined) {
  newStateMap.getByTime(timeoutThresholdTime.get).foreach { case (key, state, _) =>
    wrappedState.wrapTimingOutState(state)
    val returned = mappingFunction(batchTime, key, None, wrappedState)
    mappedData ++= returned
    newStateMap.remove(key)
  }
}
```

(Other than time taken to execute each job, it turns out that `newStateMap.remove(key)` actually *only marks* files for deletion. See "Edit" for more.)

You have to take into account the time it takes for each stage to be scheduled, and the amount of time it takes for each execution of such a stage to actually take it's turn and run. It isn't accurate because this runs as a distributed systems where other factors can come into play, making your timeout more/less accurate than you expect it to be.

---

### Edit

As @etov rightly points out, `newStateMap.remove(key)` doesn't actually remove the element from the `OpenHashMapBasedStateMap[K, S]`, but simply mark it for deletion. This is also a reason why you're seeing the expiration time adding up.

The actual relevant piece of code is here:

```
// Write the data in the parent state map while 
// copying the data into a new parent map for compaction (if needed)
val doCompaction = shouldCompact
val newParentSessionStore = if (doCompaction) {
  val initCapacity = if (approxSize > 0) approxSize else 64
  new OpenHashMapBasedStateMap[K, S](initialCapacity = initCapacity, deltaChainThreshold)
} else { null }

val iterOfActiveSessions = parentStateMap.getAll()

var parentSessionCount = 0

// First write the approximate size of the data to be written, so that readObject can
// allocate appropriately sized OpenHashMap.
outputStream.writeInt(approxSize)

while(iterOfActiveSessions.hasNext) {
  parentSessionCount += 1

  val (key, state, updateTime) = iterOfActiveSessions.next()
  outputStream.writeObject(key)
  outputStream.writeObject(state)
  outputStream.writeLong(updateTime)

  if (doCompaction) {
    newParentSessionStore.deltaMap.update(
      key, StateInfo(state, updateTime, deleted = false))
  }
}

// Write the final limit marking object with the correct count of records written.
val limiterObj = new LimitMarker(parentSessionCount)
outputStream.writeObject(limiterObj)
if (doCompaction) {
  parentStateMap = newParentSessionStore
}
```

If `deltaMap` should be compacted (marked with the `doCompaction` variable), then (and only then) is the map cleared from all the deleted instances. How often does that happen? One the delta exceeds the threadshold:

```
val DELTA_CHAIN_LENGTH_THRESHOLD = 20
```

Which means the delta chain is longer than 20 items, and there are items that have been marked for deletion.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to estimate (very roughly) how long the delay to timeout might be?

Comment: @etov See my comment to your answer.