# spark streaming mapwithstate's confuse

Tags: spark-streaming

as the code show:

```
val mappedData = new ArrayBuffer[E]
val wrappedState = new StateImpl[S]()

// Call the mapping function on each record in the data iterator, and accordingly
// update the states touched, and collect the data returned by the mapping function
dataIterator.foreach { case (key, value) =>
  wrappedState.wrap(newStateMap.get(key))
  val returned = mappingFunction(batchTime, key, Some(value), wrappedState)
  if (wrappedState.isRemoved) {
    newStateMap.remove(key)
  } else if (wrappedState.isUpdated
      || (wrappedState.exists && timeoutThresholdTime.isDefined)) {
    newStateMap.put(key, wrappedState.get(), batchTime.milliseconds)
  }
  mappedData ++= returned
}

// Get the timed out state records, call the mapping function on each and collect the
// data returned
if (removeTimedoutData && timeoutThresholdTime.isDefined) {
  newStateMap.getByTime(timeoutThresholdTime.get).foreach { case (key, state, _) =>
    wrappedState.wrapTimingOutState(state)
    val returned = mappingFunction(batchTime, key, None, wrappedState)
    mappedData ++= returned
    newStateMap.remove(key)
  }
}
```

[Spark streaming mapWithState timeout delayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552803/spark-streaming-mapwithstate-timeout-delayed#)

deltaMap ll mark for deleting when the key's removeTimedoutData=true

```
override def remove(key: K): Unit = {
val stateInfo = deltaMap(key)
if (stateInfo != null) {
  stateInfo.markDeleted()
} else {
  val newInfo = new StateInfo[S](deleted = true)
  deltaMap.update(key, newInfo)
}
```

}

the openhashmap ll remove the key when DELTA_CHAIN_LENGTH_THRESHOLD >= 20

my question is :

1: a key which in this current batch timeout ll be executed because "wrappedState.exists && timeoutThresholdTime.isDefined" and "removeTimedoutData && timeoutThresholdTime.isDefined " all true when checkpoint invokes

```
 override def checkpoint(): Unit = {
super.checkpoint()
doFullScan = true
```

}

but what does it means by executing "mappedData ++= returned" two times for a timeout key.

```
val returned = mappingFunction(batchTime, key, Some(value), wrappedState)
```

mappedData ++= returned

and

```
val returned = mappingFunction(batchTime, key, None, wrappedState)
```

mappedData ++= returned

2: when a key is marked for delete but not remove from openhashmap ,then next batch data which contain this key comes,"wrappedState.exists && timeoutThresholdTime.isDefined" and "removeTimedoutData && timeoutThresholdTime.isDefined" still all true  and they ll be executed another times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i reviewed the code of mapwithstate again and got answer
my question is :

1: a key which in this current batch timeout ll be executed because "wrappedState.exists && timeoutThresholdTime.isDefined" and "removeTimedoutData && timeoutThresholdTime.isDefined " all true when checkpoint invokes

a key this current batch timeout then the key have to wait for "doFullScan = true" which means "batchtime*DEFAULT_CHECKPOINT_DURATION_MULTIPLIER(defalut:10)",now the key already timeout for sometimes and "doFullScan = true",the key ll be update it's state first:

```
  if (wrappedState.isUpdated|| (wrappedState.exists && timeoutThresholdTime.isDefined)) {
    newStateMap.put(key, wrappedState.get(), batchTime.milliseconds)
  }
```

then the key meet the conditions :

```
 if (removeTimedoutData && timeoutThresholdTime.isDefined) {
  newStateMap.getByTime(timeoutThresholdTime.get).foreach { case (key, state, _) =>
    wrappedState.wrapTimingOutState(state)
    val returned = mappingFunction(batchTime, key, None, wrappedState)
    mappedData ++= returned
    newStateMap.remove(key)
  }
```

in this code,first of all Get all the keys and states whose updated time is older than the give threshold time and then change the key's flag   "defined = true timingOut = true removed = false updated = false"

the code "mappingFunction(batchTime, key, None, wrappedState)" ll be executed and the value of this key ll be None and in mapwihtstateFunction u can do something by "if(state.isTimeout){dosomething}"

questions 2

a key was marked as delete in stateMap then it ll be remove form openhashmap when "DELTA_CHAIN_LENGTH_THRESHOLD >= 20" but even if the key not be removed from openhashmap and u can not get it from statMap because statemap do not return a key with "delete flag"